# linux workqueues - How to ensure, that the worker thread does not go away from a specific CPU?

Tags: linux-kernel

The workqueue api provides queue_work_on()
to queue a worker thread to a specific CPU,
but in it's comments it states:
"We queue the work to a specific CPU, 
the caller must ensure it can't go away."

Does this simply mean, that one must use a workqueue, 
that was not declared with the WQ_UNBOUND flag or does it require more preparation before queueing?

Comment: `the caller must ensure it can't go away.` = `the caller must ensure the CPU can't go away.` So, until you want to use CPU hotpluging, there is nothing to care of.